# Best Practices for programmatically using autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

I am using `auto layout` throughout my whole app programmatically but I am really struggling to make my App look good on all devices (especially  struggling with the iPhone SE). Here is an example of my `StartViewController` (SE, 8 & 11 Pro Max):

[image]

As you can see the view looks pretty good on the iPhone 8 and 11 Pro Max. However on the iPhone SE it's quite bad. I don't quite get why because there would be enough space to layout all the views like in iPhone 8 ?? For some reason I think the `buttons` and `labels` are bigger (might just be an illusion).

My question is how I can fix that issue? What are best practices? Shrinking the `fontSize`? Making the `buttons` smaller ? What is the best way to get a dynamic layout that works for every iPhone? Apparently I am using Auto-Layout not in the best way...

Here is how I constrain the `views` from the picture:

```
//MARK: setupViews
func setUpViews(){

    view.addSubview(backgroundImage)
    view.addSubview(willkommenLabel)
    view.addSubview(textLabel)
    view.addSubview(emailButton)
    emailButton.addSubview(emailImage)
    view.addSubview(oderLabel)
    view.addSubview(lineLeft)
    view.addSubview(lineRight)
    view.addSubview(facebookButton)
    facebookButton.addSubview(facebookLogo)
    view.addSubview(googleButton)
    googleButton.addSubview(googleLogo)
    view.addSubview(appleButton)
    appleButton.addSubview(appleLogo)
    view.addSubview(documentsLabel)

    backgroundImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    backgroundImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    backgroundImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    backgroundImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true

    willkommenLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 80).isActive = true
    willkommenLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    willkommenLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true


    textLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: willkommenLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    textLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    textLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true

    emailButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    emailButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
    emailButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textLabel.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
    emailButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

    emailImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailButton.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    emailImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailButton.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    emailImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
    emailImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true

    oderLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    oderLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
    oderLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true

    lineLeft.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oderLabel.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    lineLeft.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    lineLeft.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oderLabel.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

    lineRight.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oderLabel.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    lineRight.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oderLabel.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    lineRight.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true

    facebookButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailButton.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    facebookButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailButton.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    facebookButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oderLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 55 + 10).isActive = true
    facebookButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

    facebookLogo.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: facebookButton.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    facebookLogo.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: facebookButton.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    facebookLogo.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
    facebookLogo.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true

    googleButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailButton.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    googleButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailButton.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    googleButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: facebookButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 55 + 10).isActive = true
    googleButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

    googleLogo.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: googleButton.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    googleLogo.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: googleButton.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    googleLogo.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
    googleLogo.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true

    appleButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailButton.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    appleButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailButton.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    appleButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: googleButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 55 + 10).isActive = true
    appleButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

    appleLogo.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: appleButton.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    appleLogo.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: appleButton.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    appleLogo.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
    appleLogo.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true

    documentsLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    documentsLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    documentsLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true

}
```

Comment: UI design is not as easy as one might think. That's why **very good designers** get paid **very good money**.  It looks like you have too much space above your "Willkommen..." label; you may want to enable "Autoshrink" on your "Werde Mitglied..." label; you may want the buttons to be a little shorter on smaller devices; usw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try.

It uses a few percentage heights (based on your original layout on an iPhone 8 screen).

I didn't change any of your existing code. Just add the following `func` and change your call from:

```
setupViews()
```

to

```
setupViewsDon()
```

Should be clear from the comments where you might want to make any adjustments... but hopefully this will get you close to your goal - and maybe you'll find a few tips for future use:

```
func setupViewsDon(){

    // setting these properties here, so I don't have to change your original initialization
    willkommenLabel.numberOfLines = 1
    willkommenLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    willkommenLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5

    textLabel.numberOfLines = 2
    textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    textLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5

    // prevent willkommenLabel from being compressed or streched
    willkommenLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
    willkommenLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)

    // prevent oderLabel from being compressed or streched
    oderLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
    oderLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)

    // prevent documentsLabel from being compressed or streched
    documentsLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
    documentsLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)

    view.addSubview(backgroundImage)
    view.addSubview(willkommenLabel)
    view.addSubview(textLabel)
    view.addSubview(emailButton)
    emailButton.addSubview(emailImage)
    view.addSubview(oderLabel)
    view.addSubview(lineLeft)
    view.addSubview(lineRight)
    view.addSubview(facebookButton)
    facebookButton.addSubview(facebookLogo)
    view.addSubview(googleButton)
    googleButton.addSubview(googleLogo)
    view.addSubview(appleButton)
    appleButton.addSubview(appleLogo)
    view.addSubview(documentsLabel)

    backgroundImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    backgroundImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    backgroundImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    backgroundImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true

    // add a layout guide for percentage top spacing
    let topSpaceGuide = UILayoutGuide()
    view.addLayoutGuide(topSpaceGuide)

    // based on iPhone 8 ... 80-pts from top
    // will be shorter on smaller devices, taller on larger devices
    topSpaceGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    topSpaceGuide.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 80.0 / 667.0).isActive = true

    willkommenLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topSpaceGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    willkommenLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    willkommenLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true

    // textLabel top constrained to willkommenLabel bottom
    textLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: willkommenLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    textLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    textLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true

    // textLabel height = a percentage of view height using 100-pts based on an iPhone 8
    //  priority = .defaultHigh so it can be compressed if needed (on smaller devices)
    let c = textLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 100.0 / 667.0)
    c.priority = .defaultHigh
    c.isActive = true

    // set email button height
    emailButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

    // set other button heights equal to emailButton
    facebookButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailButton.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    googleButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailButton.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    appleButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailButton.heightAnchor).isActive = true

    // add the logo images to the buttons, and make their heights relative to button heights
    //      in case you want to change the button heights

    for (btn, img) in [(emailButton, emailImage), (facebookButton, facebookLogo), (googleButton, googleLogo), (appleButton, appleLogo)] {
        btn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
        btn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
        btn.addSubview(img)
        img.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        img.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        img.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
        img.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: img.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    emailButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    oderLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
    facebookButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oderLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
    googleButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: facebookButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    appleButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: googleButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

    // make sure appleButton stays above documentsLabel
    appleButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: documentsLabel.topAnchor, constant: -20.0).isActive = true

    // horizontal arrangement of oderLabel and left/right lines
    oderLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    oderLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true

    lineLeft.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oderLabel.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    lineLeft.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    lineLeft.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oderLabel.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

    lineRight.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oderLabel.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    lineRight.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oderLabel.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    lineRight.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true

    // documentsLabel stay at bottom
    documentsLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    documentsLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    documentsLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true

}
```

Comment: sorry I was quite busy and I am just seeing this answer now. This is perfect!! Great work, really appreciated. Exactly what I was looking for. I will go through the code and let you know if I anything is unclear :)

Comment: I created a Room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213371/room-for-chris-and-donmag

Answer (score 0):

Actually this depnds on how you wan the layout to look in  every device , so if you want fixed height for all elements then you should wrap all elements inside a scrollview that will scroll for small devices and act if not exists in large devices , or if you need to make elements fit in screen in all devices then you should make height constraints proportional to screen height

Comment: I am using a `ScrollView` for that in another `ViewController`. But for the first screen a ScrollView is very unintuitive in my opinion. So what are the *UI Rules* here? Just make the Buttons and Labels smaller ?? And how exactly can I make the fontSize dynamically ?

Comment: this is a design thing , but to me i prefer to scale it instead of making it scroll , you can use scaleFont to fit property of label/button you can create a vc function extension that detected current device and return a font size that you use when creating all elements

Answer (score 0):

If you want your design to work perfect in all devices then you have to avoid setting constant values as much as you can unless it's necessary, here you are setting heights and paddings fixed numbers, trying to set them related to screen size, for example you can here set all buttons in a view and set it's height to half of screen would be :

```
  Let height = view.frame.size.height / 2
  buttonView.heightAnchor.constrains(equalTo: height).isActive = true
```

And also insert the buttons inside a stackView covers the buttonsview and set it to fill equally for buttons. So you would have all buttons equally and not hard coded, as well as dynamic view of the buttons related ro screen size of whichever device runs the app